# Make highlighted input field 'unhighlighted' when user starts typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, input, highlight

I made a simple form with javascript that highlights red fields if you click the "join" button and you leave a field blank.

Even after you fill it, until the "Join" button is pressed, it will continue to stay red. So instead of on click, I just want the highlight to be taken off once the user begins typing.

JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/LCBradley3k/xqcJS/6/
Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


      /*  setTimeout(function(){ 
        $('.inputs').show("slide", { direction: "down" }, 1000);
        }, 2000);
    });*/

    $('#join').click(function(){

        var correct = true;

        $('input[type="text"]').each(function(indx){
            var $currentField = $(this);
            if ($currentField.val() === ''){
                $currentField.addClass('empty');
                correct = false;
            } else{
                $currentField.removeClass('empty');
            }

        });
        if (correct) {
            $('#answer').html('Thank You!');
            setTimeout(function(){
        $('.inputs').hide("slide", { direction: "up" }, 1000);
        }, 2000);
        } else {
        $('#answer').html('Please fill highlighted fields.') ;     
        }



    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `keyup` handler on the form inputs to remove the class:

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function (event) {
    var $currentField = $(this);
    if ($currentField.val() !== '') {
        $currentField.removeClass('empty');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6TTfP/)**

Answer (score 0):

Sure, just bind to keydown.

http://jsfiddle.net/xqcJS/7/

```
if ($currentField.val() === ''){
    $currentField.addClass('empty');
    correct = false;
    $currentField.one('keydown',function(){
        $currentField.removeClass('empty');
    });
```

Comment: @theshadowmonkey `.one()` is used just once: *Attach a handler to an event for the elements. The handler is executed at most once per element.*

Comment: Won't the `keydown` event trigger even if the user tabs away from the input field, without placing any text inside?

Comment: Yes, if that's a problem it should be coded around. I don't see it as a problem, it'l just get caught again when the form submits.

Comment: I would even go as far as doing it on focus instead.

Comment: @KevinB I guess that makes sense within the context of this only being validated upon submission and not as text is entered.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[type="text"]').keydown(function() {
    if ( $(this).val != "" )
        $(this).removeClass('empty');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either use focus or use keyup.

```
$('input[type="text"]').keyup(function(e){
  $(this).removeClass('empty');
})
```

You can replace keyup with focus if you want to use the focus since it won't trigger the event each time you type.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following piece of code:

```
$('input[type="text"]').focus(function() {            
   $(this).removeClass('empty');
});
```

The class 'empty' will be removed when you focus in on field.